# OsError Python en Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu

He creado un script con Python y al ejecutarlo me responde con este mensaje:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pruebaHIDS.py", line 6, in <module>
    for filename in listdir("/Escritorio/Scripts"):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Escritorio/Scripts'
```

El problema viene porque el directorio en concreto Escritorio/Scripts no está vacío.

¿Se le ocurre a alguién alguna solución o ya le ha pasado antes?

**Edición:**

Cambiando la ruta por "/home/ldh/Escritorio/Scripts/" como se ha aconsejado en los comentarios obtengo un nuevo error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "pruebaHIDS.py", line 11, in <module>
    print "excepción: " % e
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Adjunto el código que estoy ejecutando:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import hashlib
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir, islink
for filename in listdir("/home/ldh/Escritorio/Scripts/"):
 if not isdir(filename) and not islink(filename):
  try:
   f = open(filename)
  except IOError, e:
   print "excepción: " % e
 else:
  data = f.read()
  f.close()
  print "** %s **" % filename
  for algorithm in hashlib.algorithms:
   h = getattr(hashlib, algorithm)(data)
   print "%s: %s" % (algorithm, h.hexdigest())
   print ""
```

Comment: Yo Yo, bienvenido a SOes. Podrias mostrarnos tu codigo?

Comment: `/Escritorio/Scripts` es una **ruta absoluta** ¿Es este tu caso? En cambio, `Escritorio/Scripts` es una ruta relativa a tu directorio actual. Por favor aporta más información como la ruta absoluta a esa carpeta y su relación con el directorio de trabajo o donde se localiza el script junto al código que ocasiona el error. `os.listdir` no lanza excepciones porque el directorio no esté vacío...

Comment: Buenas noches, gracias por tu atención. Te copio el código que estoy ejecutando:

La ruta es absoluta.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import hashlib
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir, islink
for filename in listdir("home/ldh/Escritorio/Scripts/"):
 if not isdir(filename) and not islink(filename):
  try:
   f = open(filename)
  except IOError, e:
   print "excepción: " % e
 else:
  data = f.read()
  f.close()
  print "** %s **" % filename
  for algorithm in hashlib.algorithms:
   h = getattr(hashlib, algorithm)(data)
   print "%s: %s" % (algorithm, h.hexdigest())
   print ""

Comment: Yo Yo no agregues el código en comentarios, agregalo a tu pregunta usando el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/108402/edit) que hay debajo de la misma. Si es una ruta absoluta debería ser `"/home/ldh/Escritorio/Scripts/"`

Comment: Muchas gracias FJ he corregido la ruta y ahora ha saltado a otro fallo, te copio lo que me dice. Un saludo.

ldh@ldh-VirtualBox:~/Escritorio$ python pruebaHIDS.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "pruebaHIDS.py", line 11, in <module>
 
   print "excepción: " % e

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como son resueltas las rutas en Linux la ruta:

```
"home/ldh/Escritorio/Scripts/"
```

es una ruta relativa y es tratada como tal. Esto ocasiona que busque el directorio `home` dentro del directorio de trabajo actual, o del script en su defecto.

Se debe agregar una barra inclinada a la izquierda para que la ruta sea tratada como absoluta:

```
"/home/ldh/Escritorio/Scripts/"
```

---

**Edición:**

Tu segundo error se debe a que en la linea:

```
print "excepción: " % e
```

Pasas el argumento e para que sea formateado pero no incluyes el indicador oportuno en el propio string. Deberia ser:

```
print "excepción: %s" % e
```